# Twitter signin error in react-native-twitter-signin in iOS only

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, twitterkit, twitter-login

I've setup `react-native-twitter-signin` package as like in documentation and works perfectly on Android. But I'm getting this error on iOS.

`Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1): Error: Twitter signin error.`
[image]

Is it due to callback issue?

Comment: Yes, you need to configure in a twitter developer account.

Comment: Yeah I added twitterkit-CONSUMER_KEY:// to callback url and got this resolved. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks @aryalprakash.
I also been need just add twitterkit-CONSUMER_KEY://

Comment: can anyone tell where you have added `twitterkit-CONSUMER_KEY:// ` please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem for me was the I didn't put `twitterkit-CONSUMER_KEY://` in the Twitter developer site.

1. Go to https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps/
2. Pick you app then press edit button on right side

   [image]
3. Edit the details, and scroll to Callback URLs
4. Add twitterkit- (delete this and put your `CONSUMER_KEY` instead). It should look something like this:

   ```
   twitterkit-23232123ddskdj231jhds
   ```

   [image]

Comment: You're the man! Thanks a lot! This was driving me crazy